# How to access Windows 10 scaling value in Java?

Tags: java, windows, scaling, dpi

I'm creating a simple sticky note app in Java, and use the following code to set its font size:

```
    Font systemDefault = super.getFont();

    int style = systemDefault.getStyle();
    int size = systemDefault.getSize();
    String name = "Arial";

    noteFont = new Font(name, style, size);
```

This works perfectly fine for Windows systems with the scaling value set at 100%, but will produce an inadequately small font size if the system scaling value is set at anything higher. (For example, I use a 200% scaling value on my Surface Pro.)

Is there any way that I could access the Windows scaling value from my Java application and use that value to adjust the provided system font size according to scale?

Comment: There's a [question over on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display) talking about this sort of problem.  It doesn't answer your question about how to do it programmatically, but if you can't find an answer here, it might give you some alternatives.